# BIM 360 Project creation template

Tags: autodesk-forge

I have an automation set up via flow that creates projects then adds users to the newly created project.

When a template is specified, it does not copy any of the folder structure or role base permissions. There are no error codes thrown and acts as if the entire thing was completed successfully.

Does the API support this, or am i reading the documentation incorrectly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Template attribute will only replicate folder structure for Classic Field unfortunately. There is an enhancement request in the backlog for other BIM 360 services, but has not been brought up to a sprint yet. As of now it will not replicate what you are looking for.