# BIM 360 Project Creation, Template Duplicate Folders (Update Request)

Tags: autodesk-forge

Related to this 2-year-old question: [BIM 360 Project creation template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58733421/bim-360-project-creation-template)

Is there still not a way to replicate the Web UI option "Activate Document Management" -> "Apply a project template" that duplicates folder structure and role-based permissions?

[image: Apply a project template]

Specifically, I'm looking at requests to create a project

> POST projects https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/bim360/v1/reference/http/projects-POST/ supplying a `template_project_id` value

and then activate with

> POST users/import v2 https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/bim360/v1/reference/http/projects-project_id-users-import-POST/

I don't see any other template input in the API documentation besides the first request, and that does not appear to bring folder structure along.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

unfortunately, what you found is correct currently, creating a project from a template with folder structure and role permission is not supported with current API, but you can achieve that by yourself as shown in a sample project at https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-bim360.project.setup.tool.

This is actually a high requested wish HQ-5023 as you can see at https://fieldofviewblog.wordpress.com/2019/06/15/bim-360-acc-api-known-issues-and-wishes/#more-4424 , our engineering is actively working on that, we will update you at our blog if any progress.

Answer (score 0):

Based on reading the documentation, and running some tests, this appears to be unavailable still. I would very much like to be proven incorrect by someone at Autodesk! Thanks.